# Replace all string fields in all documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a very heterogeneous data structure with lots of nested arrays and objects. Something like this:

```json
{
    ...,
    "centralPath": "/home/userA/path/to/central",
    "pathObjs": [{
        "differentPath": "/home/userA/path/to/1"
    }, {
        "differentPath": "/home/userA/path/to/2"
    }],
    ...
}
```

Is there a possibility to update all string fields of all documents and replace `"/home/userA"` with `"/home/userB"` without writing update operations for each single field individually?

Comment: there is no straight way to do this in dynamic structure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight way to do this in dynamic structure,

There is a option for custom function [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) starting from MongoDB 4.4,

> Defines a custom aggregation function or expression in JavaScript.
>
> You can use the `$function` operator to define custom functions to implement behavior not supported by the MongoDB Query Language. See also [$accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/#mongodb-group-grp.-accumulator).
>
> **IMPORTANT:**
>
> Executing JavaScript inside an aggregation expression may decrease performance. Only use the `$function` operator if the provided pipeline operators cannot fulfill your application's needs.

- the js function will convert root document in stringify format
- will search for `/home/userA` in above string and replace by `/home/userB`
- parse string to JSON string and return
- `$mergeObject` to merge above converted document and `_id` because some time object id will cause problem to replace in root.
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above document to root

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
  [{
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          {
            $function: {
              body: function(root) {
                var str = JSON.stringify(root);
                str = str.replace(new RegExp("/home/userA", 'g'), "/home/userB");
                return JSON.parse(str);
              },
              args: ["$$ROOT"],
              lang: "js"
            }
          },
          { _id: "$_id" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OCq_wtE0dFf)

Comment: Thanks for that! I fear it will not work if I have other fields with different types in my documents, right? When I try your approach, I get following error: `"errmsg" : "The dollar ($) prefixed field '$oid' in 'users.0.$oid' is not valid for storage."`

Comment: it will cause the problem in object id type field, so I have prevented for `_id` field but your structure is dynamic so there would be more fields having object type id like your error said for fields `users` array of object ids, will see if any solution to prevent this error.